# How do I use existing sourcecode for integration in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, package

I am building an application that is going to be using the functions in it. I am not sure how to import this as a package in my project. Or even if this is the correct way to go about using this.

Please help.

Comment: Post the code, not a link to it.

Comment: So basically you don't understand the Java classpath, or how to work with libraries in Eclipse?

Comment: @Gimby Yes I believe so

Comment: @blahfunk There is no code to post. Just wanted the concept.

Comment: @DivR You state "there is source code here"... What would I expect to find clicking on that link? Do not attempt to use links to remote sites here. How do we know you aren't sending us to some malicious site?

Comment: While I agree with blahfunk the site seems to be trustworthy, It links to prof from nottingham. I would guess he told his students to set up the project and 1 or more ended up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download the source/javadoc/jar they have specified in #4.

1. Create a new "Java project" in Eclipse.
2. Use File->Import and choose "Archive file". Browse and select the source zip file.

[image: ss]

3. Now you can right click the project, and modify the build path: add the  jMathPlot jar to classpath.

Answer (score 1):

Download the jar(https://github.com/yannrichet/jmathplot/blob/master/dist/jmathplot.jar) and  add it to your application classpath.

You can import and use functions available in that project.